# Include doesn't display file

Tags: php

I want to display a page through an include. For more user-friendliness the htaccess redirects to the a specific page (currently htest). From the URL (like /user/24) do I get the necessary information for the links which I include into the include. It works as a link, but not for include. So I don't see a page. But why?

```
$request  = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


$params   = explode("/", str_ireplace(array('http://', 'https://'), '', $request));
$ur = '/'.$params[1].'.php?u='.$params[2];
echo "<a href='".$ur."'>test</a>";
include $ur; //doesnt work
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I've ben working with this [example](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

`include` expects a file path in the context of the server. Your `.htaccess` file is not going to have any effect here since this tells the webserver how to handle incoming requests (from your browser, etc.)

Comment: But shouldn't it also effect the link itself? The link to the file on the same space works fine. Or how could it be solved?
Because it seemed that it could have worked in earlier versions (added a link to an example).

Comment: You'll have to find the path to this file on your local machine (e.g. `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/your_project/your_file.php`) and pass this to include. Or, use a relative path, with may just be `your_file.php` if both files are in the same folder.